# Reference Error: Autheticated is not defined in Laravel-React Boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, laravel

1. Download Laravel-React Boilerplate project from Github.
2. composer install and npm install.
3. Create DB and php artisan migrate and seed.
4. npm  run dev and npm run prod.
5. php artisan serve.

I followed the instruction [on the Github](https://github.com/Nilanth/laravel-react-boilerplate) but I had an error like the above one.
The error in Google Chrome console like this:
"Reference Error: Authenticated is not defined in app.js: 2".

In auth.php:

```
 'guards' => [
   'web' => [
       'driver' => 'session',
       'provider' => 'users',
   ],

   'api' => [
       'driver' => 'passport',
       'provider' => 'users',
   ],
],

'providers' => [
   'users' => [
       'driver' => 'passport',
       'model' => App\Users::class,
   ],
```

If you have any solution, please tell me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the bug to try like this:

In app.js

```
const auth = firebase.auth(); 
const db = firebase.database();
```